# What font is used in this banner from a Think With Google Newsletter?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

I have not been able to identify this font using several differnet online services like Identifont, WhatTheFont, What Font Is etc., looking through the fonts I already own, looking through the Google Font Library and using the Photoshop font matching tool.

The font is featured in a banner at the bottom of a newsletter from Think With Google titled "How Fenty shook up the beauty industry by rewriting marketing rules". The text is with the font in question is "creativity: knowing which rules can be".

Image of the font:
[image: Image of font in question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer : **It's Product sans or Google sans...** but wait....

=> this is mostly discussed font among many font related forums and sites that this font is downloadable? Yes!! you can download it from [here](https://befonts.com/product-sans-font.html) and license says it's free for personal and commercial use! but is it truth??

=> According to google this is [**clearly unavailable**](https://fonts.google.com/license/productsans) for uses! so even i suggest you to avoid downloading and using it. as workaround you can use [Open Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans)! but it can beat product sans when it comes to feels!

Here is font demo

[image]

[image]

and yes I'm sure that this is Product sans :)

As @Luciano doubted about 'r'; now I'm clear that it's product sans because it's alternated version of 'r' is exact as mentioned in question! [Source is here](https://www.dafontfree.io/product-sans-font-family/)

[image]

Best Regard :)

Comment: Are you sure? I feel the lowercase S and C are more soft in this font than any pf those two. Also, the lowercase E does not quite fit in the softer of the two.

Comment: you can see my updated answer . it's same :)

Comment: the terminal in the "r" is different in your examples, are you sure sure sure that it's Product Sans?

Comment: @Luciano Product sans have many styles and the above example made in regular font. and i dont even downloaded yet because this scr are made from befonts site. and as far as i know only product sans are the font which google using nowadays .

Comment: and it's seems more than 90% are same as Product sans. but if it's not product sans then it might be different style of Product sans but i believe this is product sans only :D

Comment: @Luciano you can see my edited answer. it gives clarity that it's Product Sans :) and don't know if it's still not because it's their private font and google can update any glyphs whenever they want :D

Comment: oh I didn't know Product had alternate characters, carry on.

Comment: even I didn't know and still we can't see because there is no latest font for demo XD it happens though.